# Dynamics 365 plugin not sending emails C#

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-365

I'm trying to send an email when a record of a specific type is created. I followed the guide posted here: https://carldesouza.com/send-dynamics-365-email-using-c/. The code executes fine, all the system user internal email addresses are approved and I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work. Any advice/tips/suggestions are appreciated :)

```
// Id of Email-Case Distribution List Team
Guid teamId = new Guid("1028e7db-6666-7777-8888-000c29fc4e14");
// main query returing users
QueryExpression userQuery = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
// take all columns
userQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
// this is the intersect condition
LinkEntity teamLink = new LinkEntity("systemuser", "teammembership", "systemuserid", "systemuserid", JoinOperator.Inner);
// this is the condition to use the specific Team
ConditionExpression teamCondition = new ConditionExpression("teamid", ConditionOperator.Equal, teamId);
// add the condition to the intersect
teamLink.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(teamCondition);
// add the intersect to the query
userQuery.LinkEntities.Add(teamLink);
//get the results
EntityCollection retrievedUsers = proxy.RetrieveMultiple(userQuery);
// fetch the results
List<ActivityParty> ToEmailList = new List<ActivityParty>();
foreach (Entity user in retrievedUsers.Entities)
{
    ActivityParty toActivityParty = new ActivityParty();
    SystemUser person = user.ToEntity<SystemUser>();
    toActivityParty.PartyId = new EntityReference("systemuser", person.Id);
    toActivityParty.AddressUsed = person.InternalEMailAddress;
    ToEmailList.Add(toActivityParty);
}
// We will send the email from this current user
List<ActivityParty> FromEmailList = new List<ActivityParty>();
ActivityParty fromActivityParty = new ActivityParty();
fromActivityParty.PartyId = new EntityReference("systemuser", context.InitiatingUserId);
SystemUser initiatingUser = proxy.Retrieve("systemuser", context.InitiatingUserId, new ColumnSet(true)).ToEntity<SystemUser>();
fromActivityParty.AddressUsed = initiatingUser.InternalEMailAddress;
FromEmailList.Add(fromActivityParty);


Email email = new Email();
email.From = FromEmailList.ToArray();
email.To = ToEmailList.ToArray();
email.RegardingObjectId = new EntityReference("incident", targetIncident.Id);
email.Subject = "Administrative Rule Review file was created.";
email.Description = "Administrative Rule Review file was created.";
email.DirectionCode = true;
Guid emailId = proxy.Create(email);

// Use the SendEmail message to send an e-mail message.
SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest = new SendEmailRequest
{
    EmailId = emailId,
    TrackingToken = "",
    IssueSend = true
};

SendEmailResponse sendEmailresp = (SendEmailResponse)proxy.Execute(sendEmailRequest);
Console.WriteLine("Email sent");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: On closer inspection, it appears that the status is Pending Send...

Comment: Is the sender emailbox tested and enabled, SSS configured for outgoing settings ? any errors in mailbox test run? -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/why-email-message-sent-have-pending-send-status